# How can I specialize a standard concept for my own class?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a template function that should work for all integral types:

```
#include <concepts>
template<typename T>
bool odd(T n) requires std::integral<T>
{
  return n & T(1);
}
```

Now I want to use this function with some user defined integral type, e.g. boost::multiprecision::cpp_int

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int n = ...
std::cout << odd(n) << std::endl;
```

gcc 10 gives

```
error: use of function ‘bool odd(T) requires  integral<T> [with T = boost::multiprecision ...
```

which is, of course, correct. What can I do to fix this, i.e. how can I specialize a standard concept for my own type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I specialize a standard concept for my own type?

You don't. Concepts can't be specialized. Type traits can be under certain circumstances, but `std::integral` isn't one that you can, so that's not the right route either.

> What can I do to fix this

You need to come up with the right concept for the set of algorithms you're using. Obviously the most literal one is:

```
template <typename T>
concept IsOddable = std::constructible_from<T, int> &&
    requires (T n) {
        { n & n } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    };
```

But don't do that. You probably need some kind of generic `Numeric` concept and add requirements for, whatever, `+`, `*`, `%`, etc. Concepts come from algorithms - so figure out the generic requirements that your algorithms are imposing and work up from there.

Comment: I figured already out: the algorithm works for all integral types (built-in and user defined), i.e. "integral" is the right concept.

Comment: @HelmutZeisel The `std::integral` concept doesn't "work for all integral types (built-in and user defined)", it's _only_ for built-in types. If you want to support user defined integral types, then `std::integral` is not the correct concept.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I added the lines

```
    template< class T >
    inline constexpr bool is_my_integral_v = false;

    template<>
    inline constexpr bool is_my_integral_v<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int> = true;
```

and changed the requirement to

```
    template<typename T>
    bool odd(T n) requires std::integral<T> || is_my_integral_v<T>
```

and now it works.

Comment: You could default `is_my_integral_v` to `std::is_integral_v<T>` and then you don't need the disjunction.